# The site template requires that the feature be installed in the farm or site collection

Tags: custom-actions, workflow-activity

I inherited a SharePoint implementation.  There is a Workflow that runs when an item in a List is created.  The old developer created some Actions using Visual Studio.  The Workflow is configurable using SharePoint Designer.  Specifically, there is a condition/action that creates a site using a ProjectSiteTemplate variable that is set through SPD.  The value in there now is a {guid}#ProjectSiteTemplate.  Workflow is failing with following message:  "Failed to create site at `http://site/rpm/11`.  SPException  The site template requires that the feature {guid} be installed in the farm or site collection".

How can I find out what Feature is missing?  Specifically, I am looking for a name.  That would help be debug or find out what I need to active or deploy.

Thanks for any tips provided.

Comment: I'm assuming you tried googling the GUID to no avail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the old developer created a feature that defines a site template. Without the feature activated, the site cannot be created because the site template is unavailable. I suggest you use PowerShell to confirm that the feature is activated in a site collection where this worked in the past (get-spfeature -identity {guid}). Then, activate the feature in the site collection you are testing the workflow on. If the feature isn't available, you may need to track down the solution it was deployed from and install that solution (wsp).